# Weird behaviour while changing an object in a callback: why...?

Tags: javascript, object

This code:

```
function CHANGE(d, cb){
    d.three = 3;
    d = {};
    console.log("d was changed into:");
    console.log(d);
    cb();
  }

  var d = { one: 1, two: 2 };
  CHANGE(d, function(){
    console.log("d after the callback is: ");
    console.log(d);
  });
```

Since `d` is *rewritten* in `CHANGE()`, really ought to show `{}` as `d`. However, the result is bizarre:

```
d was changed into:
{}
d after the callback is: 
{ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
```

So, `d` had the property `three` added to it. And that's OK. Then it was assigned an empty object `{}`.

I don't know what to think.

An extra attribute be added in the callback (`three`), fine.
Then the object is rewritten. Fine. The printout shows that the object was indeed rewritten.
Then, in the callback, it shows the object with the extra `three` attribute...?!?

It would be consistent if it were either unchanged, or rewritten. But... *half* changed...?

In fact, there is no need to use a callback to show this. Even this has the same problem:

```
function CHANGE( o ){
   o.three = 3;
   o = {};
 }

 var d = { one: 1, two: 2 };
 CHANGE(d);
 console.log("d after the function is: ");
 console.log(d);
```

Here `d` is again the full object including `three`.
So, any particular reason why I cannot change the object reference altogether, but can change attributes...?

Merc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {};
```

This redefines your variable to a new object, so you lose the old reference. This means that the original isn't altered after this point.

**EDIT:**

If you want to clear an existing object of its properties and reassign some others, you could use this:

```
var a = {some:"stuff", other: "stuff"};

function clearProperties(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
         delete obj[i];
    }
}

console.log(a);
clearProperties(a);
a.newStuff = "stuff";
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
Object {some: "stuff", other: "stuff"} fiddle.jshell.net:28
Object {newStuff: "stuff"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DxzT/

Comment: Jeee so obvious. I need to sleep more. So... how would you go about changing the original object _completely_, other than returning it from the function?

Comment: @Merc I don't think this is possible in JS. :(

Comment: Ah... I mean, I *could* write a function to empty an object of all of its elements and assign a new prototype changing __proto__ but... yuck. No.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the argument you don't change the parameter, you only change what the argument (in the *function*) is assigned to.